# Simplifying Integral Inequality with e on one side and ln on the other

Tags: inequality, logarithms, integral-inequality

Can you help me finish this problem? Decimal approximations are not sufficient for credit. I wasn't sure how to simplify the left side much more (besides obviously multiplying by two and subtracting the one over) to make it look something similar enough to make a direct comparison with the right side.

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\sqrt{7}-1}}\left[\left(x^{3}+x\right) e^{-x^{2}}\right] d x \leq \ln (2) \\
&\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\sqrt{7}-1}}\left(e^{-x^{2}} x^{3}+e^{-x^{2}} x\right) d x \\
&\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\sqrt{7}-1}} e^{-x^{2}} x^{3} d x+\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\sqrt{7}-1}} e^{-x^{2}} x d x
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \text { Let } u=-x^{2} ; \text { Let } d u=-2 x \\
& -\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\sqrt{7}-1}} \frac{e^{u} u}{2} d u-\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{\sqrt{7}-1}} e^{u} d u \\
& \frac{x^{2} e^{-x^{2}}}{2}-\frac{e^{-x^{2}}}{2} \mid \sqrt{\sqrt{7}-1} \\
& \frac{e^{-x^{2}}\left(x^{2}-1\right)}{2} \mid \begin{gathered}\sqrt{\sqrt{7}-1} \\0\end{gathered}
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{gathered}
\frac{e^{-\sqrt{\sqrt{7}-1}^{2}}\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{7}-1}^{2}-1\right)}{2}-\frac{e^{0}\left(0^{2}-1\right)}{2} \leq \ln (2) \\
\frac{e^{-(\sqrt{7}-1)}(\sqrt{7}-1-1)}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \leq \ln (2) \\
\frac{e^{-\sqrt{7}+1}(\sqrt{7}-2)+1}{2} \leq \ln (2) \\
\approx 0.62 \leq 0.69
\end{gathered}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Using almost what you did
$$\int_0^a (x^3+x)\,e^{-x^2}\,dx=1-\frac{1}{2} \left(a^2+2\right) e^{-a^2}$$ which increases with $a$.

Solving for the *equality*, let $a^2=b$
$$1-\frac{1}{2} \left(b+2\right) e^{-b}=\log(2) \implies b=-2-W_{-1}\left(\frac{2 (\log (2)-1)}{e^2}\right)$$ where $W_{-1}(t)$ is the second branch of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Using the series expansion given in the liked Wikipedia page
$$W_{-1}(z)= L_1-L_2+\frac {L_2}{L_1}+\frac {L_2(L_2-2)}{2L_1^2}+\cdots$$ with $L_1=\log(-z)$ and $L_2=\log(-L_1)$ gives
$$W_{-1}\left(\frac{2 (\log (2)-1)}{e^2}\right)=-3.8315 \implies b=1.8315\implies a=1.3533$$ while $\sqrt{\sqrt{7}-1}=1.28287$.

Brute force would be to make $a=\sqrt{\sqrt{7}-1}$ in
$$1-\frac{1}{2} \left(a^2+2\right) e^{-a^2}=1-\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{7}\right) e^{1-\sqrt{7}}=0.64843  < \log(2)$$

Using the first part, you could even show that
$$\int_0^{ \sqrt{\sqrt{8}-1}} (x^3+x)\,e^{-x^2}\,dx< \log(2)$$